# Get level of each rows in a hierarchical table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, hierarchical-data

I have a table like this

```
ID    Name     Parent
-----------------------
1     Test1    NULL
2     Test2    NULL
3     Test3     1
4     Test4     3
5     Test5     2
6     Test6     4
7     Test7     3
-------------------------
```

Please help me to get level number along with each rows. Like this

```
ID    Name     Parent   Level
------------------------------
1     Test1    NULL      0
2     Test2    NULL      0
3     Test3     1        1
4     Test4     3        2
5     Test5     2        1
6     Test6     4        3
7     Test7     3        2
--------------------------------
```

So its like plotting each of the items Floor level in the hierarchy..

I missed to specify, Im using MS SQL 2012

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.), as this will strongly determine the answer you need?

Comment: You might want to do it in a recursive stored function/procedure. Could be easier to do in application

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Im using MS SQL 2012. Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can handle this using a recursive CTE without too much trouble.  In the CTE below, the first half is the base condition, which includes those top parent records themselves having no parent.  The recursive portion, which is the bottom half of the union, targets all children records.  We keep a tally of the level by adding one to whatever the value of the immediate parent was.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, Name, Parent, 0 AS level
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Parent IS NULL
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Parent, t2.level + 1
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN cte t2
        ON t1.Parent = t2.ID
)

SELECT ID, Name, Parent, Level
FROM cte
ORDER BY ID;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Sorry to ask you... what is the fastest way of finding the level of an ID. For example if I pass the ID 4, the function should return 2. Not from the final table, from the main table itself (Without level column)

Comment: I don't know of any clear way to do this.  What would be wrong with just using the CTE in my answer?

Comment: is there a way to do this in MySQL 5.7 which doesn't support the `WITH` clause